# Error after changing the section: "Unknown attribute. Attribute names are case sensitive."

Tags: c#

I have some code in first program referencing on configuration of second where `TConfig is ConfigurationSection`.

```
protected TConfig GetCustomConfig<TConfig>(string configFilePath, string sectionName) where TConfig : ConfigurationSection
{            
    var exeFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    exeFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath;
    var customConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(exeFileMap,
        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);            
    var returnConfig = customConfig.GetSection(sectionName) as TConfig; 
    return returnConfig;
}
```

Parameter *configFilePath* is the path of second program configuration. I have two versions of second program configuration.

**VersionA**

```
<InterfaceSection>
    <paramGroups>
      <paramGroup param1="param1" param2="param2"> 
      </paramGroup>
    </paramGroups>
  </InterfaceSection>
```

and **versionB**

```
<InterfaceSection>
  <paramGroups>
    <paramGroup param1="param1" param2="param2" param3="param3">        
    </paramGroup>
  </paramGroups>
</InterfaceSection>
```

In first program I am perfoming sucessfully method `GetCustomConfig(string versionAconfigFilePath, string interfaceSectionName)`. Then I execute this method for configuration version B: `GetCustomConfig(string versionBconfigFilePath, string interfaceSectionName)`. And get error: *"Unknown "param3" attribute. Attribute names are case sensitive."*

Why is the second configuration version compared to the first? If you skip downloading the first version, the second version will load successfully.

**UPDATE**

I have next definition for version B configuration section. There isn't property *param3* in version A configuration section. That's the difference between them.

```
public class MyParamGroup : ParamGroup
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("param3", DefaultValue = 60, IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)] 
    public int param3
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this["param3"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["param3"] = value;
        }
    }
}

[ConfigurationProperty("param1", DefaultValue = 60, IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)] 
public int param1
{
    get
    {
        return (int)this["param1"];
    }
    set
    {
        this["param1"] = value;
    }
}

[ConfigurationProperty("param2", DefaultValue = 60, IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)] 
public int param2
{
    get
    {
        return (int)this["param2"];
    }
    set
    {
        this["param2"] = value;
    }
}

public class ParamGroup : ConfigurationSection
{
    Somethings properties
}
```

Comment: and what you pass as `TConfig` and how this class is defined

Comment: @Selvin `TConfig` is `ConfigurationSection`

Comment: `ConfigurationSection` is abstract ... what is the implementation class and how it is defined

Comment: well, the obvious choice before asking is to check if given implementation of ConfigurationSection contains this("param3") properties ... if it does then **question should contain all necessary code to reproduce your exception**

Comment: @Selvin Sorry, you are write. `TConfig` is MyParamGroup : ParamGroup : ConfigurationSection. MyParamGroup have definitions of param1, param2 and param3 like `[ConfigurationProperty("param3", DefaultValue = 60, IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)]       
        public int param3
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)this["param3"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["param3"] = value;
            }
        }`

Comment: Don't post code in a comment.  Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60670824/edit) your question and add the code to the question.

Comment: and what you put into `ConfigurationPropertyCollection` ?